# How to evaluate $\sum_{i=0}^{j}(-1)^i{j \choose i}(j^n-i^n)^z$

Tags: sequences-and-series

We wish to evaluate this sum
$$\sum_{i=0}^{j}(-1)^i{j \choose i}(j^n-i^n)^z$$

where $j=nz$

We can use the binomial to expand $(j^n-i^n)^z$ but it is too messy after. So there must be another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum (below, $i$ means the *imaginary unit*) is [equal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%B8rlund%E2%80%93Rice_integral) to $$\frac{j!}{2\pi i}\oint_{|u|=1/r}\frac{(j^n-u^n)^z\,du}{u(1-u)\ldots(j-u)}\qquad(0<r<1/j)$$ which, after the substitution $u=1/v$, [becomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) $$(-1)^{j+z}\frac{j!}{2\pi i}\oint_{|v|=r}\frac{\big(1-(jv)^n\big)^z}{\prod_{k=1}^{j}(1-kv)}\frac{dv}{v}=\bbox[yellow,5px]{(-1)^{j+z}j!}$$

---

There's also a simple "finite differences" argument:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{j}(-1)^k\binom{j}{k}k^r=\begin{cases}\hfill 0,\hfill& r<j\\(-1)^j j!,& r=j\end{cases}$$
with which your idea doesn't seem *that* messy.

(For $r>j$, the evaluation is [more complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Explicit_formula), but we don't need it.)

Comment: (... assuming $n, z$ are positive integers.)

Comment: For the last result one may also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3250397/summing-s-n-m-sum-k-1n-1k-km-n-choose-k-for-mn-n