# Combinatorial identity: Lah numbers as sum with binomials

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial

while studying a problem about double factorial computation I faced the following (conjectured) identity

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-1-k}{n-1 \choose k}k^n = \frac{n-1}{2}n!
$$

I just tried small values of $n>1$ and noticed that the right side is a Lah number. I have and found no proof: any help ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You may see : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3250397/summing-s-n-m-sum-k-1n-1k-km-n-choose-k-for-mn-n

Comment: Thank you, but I miss some details, I have to get deeper into it. I would really like to have a combinatorial interpretation of LHS, that I still don't have...