# Prove $\sum_{n=0}^{N+1}P(n)(-1)^n\binom{N+1}{n}=0$ with degree at most $N$ of $P$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, summation, roots

If $P$ is a polynomial of degree at most $N$, we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N+1}P(n)(-1)^n\binom{N+1}{n}=0$$

---

I tried using pascal's identity $\binom{N+1}{n}=\binom{N}{n}+\binom{N}{n-1}$. I think that differences of polynomials might work.

Comment: Your idea is correct. Just expand using Pascal's identity and use induction should do. Notice $P(n)-P(n+1)$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree at most $N-1$.

Comment: You may see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3250397/summing-s-n-m-sum-k-1n-1k-km-n-choose-k-for-mn-n