# Is there a standard compact notation for $k!{n\brace k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, notation, stirling-numbers

Is there a standard compact notation for the numbers
$$
?(n,k)=\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^i\binom ki(k-i)^n\equiv k!{n\brace k} 
$$
where ${n\brace k}$ is the Stirling number of the second kind? In probabilistic applications the combination (which counts the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ objects into $k$ non-empty *distinguishable* subsets) seems to appear even more often than the Stirling numbers themselves. And if $k$ is a very long expression I would prefer to avoid to write it once more as $(\dots)!$

Comment: Nothing standard, but I write $\operatorname{sur}\left(n,k\right)$ (as it counts surjective maps).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3250397/summing-s-n-m-sum-k-1n-1k-km-n-choose-k-for-mn-n

Comment: @ZAhmed I do not need to compute the value, I am looking for a compact notation for it.

Comment: @DanielV Thank you for advice. I have found a 1992 paper of Knuth where he at length discusses the Stirling numbers but never mentions their product with respective factorial, which combinatorial meaning is the distribution of objects in *distinguishable* boxes.

Comment: I think I might be remembering something different by knuth.

Answer (score 3):

The numbers you are using are the triangular arrray
[OEIS sequence A019538](https://oeis.org/A019538).
As mentioned in an OEIS comment, they were known as the
"differences of zero" denoted by $\,\Delta^k0^n.$
They are the numbers in the leading diagonal of the
forward **difference table** of $\,x^n\,$ at $\,x=0.\,$

For example, when $\,n=4\!:$
$$ \Delta^k x^4|_{x=0} =:
\Delta^k 0^4 = 0,\;1,\;14,\;36,\;24 $$
from the forward difference table:
$$ \begin{matrix}
\Delta^4x^4 &|  &&&&& 24 \\
\Delta^3x^4 &|   &&&& 36 && 60 \\
\Delta^2x^4 &|   &&& 14 && 50 && 110 \\
\Delta^1x^4 &|   && 1 && 15 && 65 && 175  \\
x^4 &|   & 0 && 1 && 16 && 81 && 256 \\
x &|     & 0 && 1 && 2 && 3 && 4
\end{matrix} $$

This notation is used in older books such as George Boole's
*A Treatise on The Calculus of Finite Differences*. The Wikipedia article
[Finite difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) explains some of this.

In the matter of how standard, compact or convenient
this notation is in practice, there may be some differences
of  opinion.

Comment: This is a very interesting notation. Never heard about this. But in practical applications it is not convenient as $n$ and $k$ may be rather complicated expressions.